# Write unicode gif to file in python

Tags: python, image

I have a GIF file (or any image format) in unicode form:

```
>>> data
u'GIF89a,\x000\x00\ufffd\ufffd\x00\x00\x00\x00\ufffd\ufffd\ufff...
```

I want to write this to file:

```
>>> f = open('file.gif', 'wb')
>>> f.write(data)
```

But I get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /image
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-11: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: How did you generate that Unicode string in the first place? That's going to matter for the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
utf8data = data.encode('UTF-8')
open('file.gif', 'w').write(utf8data)
```

Answer (score 3):

You must encode the string to unicode explicitly

```
f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))
```